# Handlebars angular JS parse error in ng-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat div, and inside the div have select control. This code produces parse error:

```
<select name="qty" ng-model="Qty">
   <option ng-repeat="v in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" 
           value="{{v}}" ng-selected="v=={{item["menuItem.Qty"]}}">
           {{v}}        
   </option>
</select>
```

In **F12** console it prints `ng-selected="{{item[" menuitem.qty"]}}"=""`

So, I see there is an issue with handlebars and array, but just cannot figure out what exactly wrong here.

Comment: Gotcha just wanted to give the heads up since I saw you're new here, forgot about the initial delays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
ng-selected="v=={{item["menuItem.Qty"]}}"
```

To

```
ng-selected="v=={{item['menuItem.Qty']}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('App', [])
    .controller('InputCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.menuItem={};
      $scope.menuItem.Qty = 1;
      $scope.item = {};
      
    $scope.item[1] = 1;
  }]);

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="InputCtrl">
<select name="qty" ng-model="Qty" >
   <option ng-repeat="v in  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" 
           value="{{v}}" ng-bind="v" ng-selected="v==item[menuItem.Qty]">
           
   </option>
</select>
  Qty:{{Qty}}<br/>
  item:{{item}}
  </div>
```